What is a simple small scale procedure for plastination of a cucumber?
Question
In words a high school student will understand, what procedure can a student apply to plastinate a cucumber?
A cursory article on plastination can be found here.

Motivation
When someone shares a procedure on how to plastinate a human body parts, then students can be guided through that same procedure in order to a sun-flower, or rose, or carrot, or potato.
Perhaps students could enjoy making re-usable carved potato stamps to use outside of biology, in their art class.
For now, the only thing that I have seen plastinated seems to be human flesh and organs, but the original research in 1977 mentioned a cucumber.
I tried aluminum sulfate on a specimen of Gaillardia pulchella, but the results were terrible. The inflorescence was dry and crumbly, not like a proper plastinated human heart or liver.

Perhaps students would enjoy plastinating straw-hats, if they do not like potatoes. The hat would fray less easily, the hat would be waterproof in the rain, rubbery, and a plastinated straw hat would be more durable than a traditional straw hat.

I’m voting to close this question because I do not think the preservation of dead plants is a topic consistent with the general aims of this site.

I disagree somewhat with David; I think preservation of biological specimens would be a suitable topic for here. Certainly would like to see the 1977 research you refer to - a reference or link would be nice.

This falls between here and our [crafts.se] site. If you have no luck here, then try there (probably leave out the part about human body-parts but fruit n vegetables should be OK).
